# Apt removes packages when trying to install 32bit version of existing library

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.04

Specifically I am trying to install `libllvm10:i386` with `libllvm10` already on my system. Apt now tries to remove practically everything important (xorg, xwayland, java, gnome, ...). I am 99% sure this only happened after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04, since steam is now trying to install this library and I had steam running before (my guess is that the upgrade removed that).

```
$ sudo apt install libllvm10:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bogofilter bogofilter-bdb bogofilter-common docbook-xml evolution-common
  folks-common fonts-cantarell fprintd gir1.2-caribou-1.0 gir1.2-dazzle-1.0
  gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gfbgraph-0.2 gir1.2-graphene-1.0
  gir1.2-grilo-0.3 gir1.2-handy-0.0 gir1.2-lokdocview-0.1 gir1.2-mediaart-2.0
  gir1.2-rest-0.7 gir1.2-tracker-2.0 gir1.2-zpj-0.0 gnome-backgrounds
  gnome-clocks gnome-color-manager gnome-online-miners gnome-user-share
  gnome-weather icoutils jq libapache2-mod-dnssd libaribb24-0
  libavahi-gobject0 libbasicusageenvironment1 libcacard0 libcaribou-common
  libcaribou0 libcddb2 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libdouble-conversion3 libdvbpsi10
  libebml4v5 libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1
  libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libegl1 libfaad2 libfolks25
  libfprint-2-2 libfprint-2-tod1 libgfbgraph-0.2-0 libgnome-autoar-gtk-0-0
  libgroupsock8 libgsf-bin libgsl23 libgslcblas0 libgsoap-2.8.91
  libgtk-vnc-2.0-0 libgvnc-1.0-0 libixml10 libjq1 libkate1
  liblibreofficekitgtk liblivemedia77 libmanette-0.2-0 libmatroska6v5
  libmediainfo0v5 libmms0 libmpcdec6 libmusicbrainz5-2 libmusicbrainz5cc2v5
  libopenmpt-modplug1 libpam-fprintd libphodav-2.0-0 libphodav-2.0-common
  libplacebo7 libprotobuf-lite17 libproxy-tools libproxy1-plugin-webkit
  libpst4 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5-gles libqt5network5
  libqt5x11extras5 libraw19 libreofficekit-data libresid-builder0c2a
  librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2
  librygel-renderer-gst-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2 libsdl-image1.2
  libsdl1.2debian libsidplay2 libspatialaudio0 libspice-client-glib-2.0-8
  libspice-client-gtk-3.0-5 libsrt1 libtinyxml2-6a libupnp13
  libusageenvironment3 libusbredirhost1 libusbredirparser1 libva-wayland2
  libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvlccore9 libvncserver1 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libxcb-xinput0
  libxt-dev libytnef0 libzapojit-0.0-0 libzen0v5 python-wxversion
  qt5-gtk-platformtheme qttranslations5-l10n rygel rygel-playbin rygel-tracker
  sgml-data spice-client-glib-usb-acl-helper switcheroo-control vinagre
  virtualbox-dkms vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-notify
  vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-video-splitter xdg-dbus-proxy
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libatomic1:i386 libedit2:i386 libqt5gui5-gles
Suggested packages:
  qt5-image-formats-plugins qtwayland5
Recommended packages:
  libqt5svg5
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apturl caribou cheese chrome-gnome-shell evolution evolution-data-server
  evolution-plugin-bogofilter evolution-plugin-pstimport evolution-plugins
  gdm3 gir1.2-champlain-0.12 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0
  gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gtkchamplain-0.12
  gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-6 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0
  gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome gnome-calendar gnome-contacts gnome-control-center
  gnome-core gnome-documents gnome-games gnome-getting-started-docs
  gnome-initial-setup gnome-maps gnome-music gnome-nibbles
  gnome-online-accounts gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
  gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver gnome-shell-extension-prefs
  gnome-shell-extension-top-icons-plus gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
  gnome-shell-extensions gnome-sound-recorder gnome-startup-applications
  gnome-sushi gnome-todo gnome-tweaks gnome-user-docs gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0
  gstreamer1.0-gl libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni
  libchamplain-0.12-0 libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8
  libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-pango20
  libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libevolution libfolks-eds25
  libgl1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglu1-mesa libglx-mesa0 libglx0
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libllvm10 libmutter-6-0 libqt5gui5
  libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5svg5 libqt5widgets5 libtotem0
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 libxatracker2 libyelp0 lightsoff
  megasync mesa-utils mesa-vulkan-drivers mutter nautilus-megasync
  nautilus-share openjdk-11-jre openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre playonlinux
  python-wxgtk3.0 quadrapassel rhythmbox-plugins shotwell steam-launcher
  swell-foop totem totem-plugins ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
  ubuntu-docs ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-session update-manager
  update-notifier virtualbox virtualbox-qt vlc vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-skins2
  vlc-plugin-video-output vlc-plugin-visualization x11-utils xorg
  xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
  xwayland yelp zenity
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libatomic1:i386 libedit2:i386 libllvm10:i386 libqt5gui5-gles
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 140 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 18,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 771 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Hit:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:6 http://www.geogebra.net/linux stable InRelease                           
Hit:7 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Hit:11 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease             
Hit:12 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                    
Get:13 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_20.04 ./ InRelease [2.441 B]     
Hit:14 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Hit:15 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease             
Hit:17 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease           
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu focal InRelease        
Hit:19 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease           
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/apps/ubuntu focal InRelease      
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:16 https://apt.llvm.org/focal llvm-toolchain-focal-10 InRelease  
Hit:20 https://apt.llvm.org/focal llvm-toolchain-focal-9 InRelease
Hit:22 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Fetched 2.441 B in 6s (402 B/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
32 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

```
$ apt-cache policy libllvm10:i386
libllvm10:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: I see 2 potential issues: you have held back updates, and you have orphaned outdated packages.  I suggest running `sudo apt autoremove` as suggested when you run `sudo apt update`.  Review the packages before confirming. Then you should install new updates with `sudo apt upgrade`.  Then you can install new software. Please report back

Comment: @Nmath The orphaned packages are from the removal it suggested, there are no orphaned packages. I have upgraded what I could, the rest were held back (gir1.2-polkit-1.0 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 mailutils mailutils-common policykit-1) and I manually installed them (library changes). No change in output trying to install libllvm10

Comment: @user535733 As I said, using autoremove removes nothing because they *aren't*. My system is now completely up-to-date (0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded)

Comment: Great! Please refresh your `sudo apt install libllvm10:i386` output

Comment: @user535733 Nothing changed

Comment: Your output currently in the Question says "*1 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 140 to remove and 29 not upgraded.*" instead of 0, X, Y, and 0.

Comment: @user535733 Updated it, though that changes literally nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a version mismatch of `libllvm10` and `libllvm10:i386` (10.0.1 and 10.0.0 respectively). Downgrading solved the problem.

```
$ apt-cache policy libllvm10
libllvm10:
  Installed: 1:10.0.1~++20200708122807+ef32c611aa2-1~exp1~20200707223407.61
  Candidate: 1:10.0.1~++20200708122807+ef32c611aa2-1~exp1~20200707223407.61
  Version table:
 *** 1:10.0.1~++20200708122807+ef32c611aa2-1~exp1~20200707223407.61 500
        500 http://apt.llvm.org/focal llvm-toolchain-focal-10/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```